# Downloading file with OkHttpClient fails from downloading CloudFront URL

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ssl, okhttp

I am trying to migrate from the horrible `DownloadManager` api to `OkHttpClient` api but I am running into a weird connection issue I never saw with `DownloadManager`. Download files from https://testfiledownload.com/ worked without problems using `OkHttpClient` thought, so I am not sure what the problem with my url is from CloudFront. This is my code:

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
val request = Request.Builder().url("https://d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/notification/ffc888ca-69d6-48f7-8225-58b3a5010f9c?Expires=1701371587&Signature=Lx4lwBHnWEwtnAeKPzFq15nRMsU2hUXXTQ1OjlDDsSBjA5hhxx~0eQocaB37QXPUnoF8uYWNcz~fYliUSRFl2rsx70iAgAb45SNwh5MDqEIhAwQ1oDlU3l5etxflzqHMHY7KewS3mw1y1osS~Jg7eOCOazKUl3CL1C0iBY6eTxa85MWlcTkocfKgm2TlwNtV~Epdlj1vEA1XSK3TWLLHUP6NnBX2W1lLxZLudZfL-JWFDQvA2peON7OiHRQ~okF28xHumVlQr0Ao7-DRBwAW9xn3k8jIbfca-kUhe8otnBOXVh~lMwf3HZ04SwKpTY8txHRzBRjtQkezPym9MvGfaw__&Key-Pair-Id=K1SS0UK0I5H897").build()
val response = client.newCall(request).execute().body.bytes()
```

The url downloads the file perfectly in my browser, but the code fails with this stacktrace. Any ideas?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-20-thread-1
Process: com.myappapp.myapp, PID: 13514
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/[2600:9000:20b4:e00:3:24f0:f980:21]:443
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:256)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectTcp(ConnectPlan.kt:128)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.FastFallbackExchangeFinder$launchTcpConnect$1.runOnce(FastFallbackExchangeFinder.kt:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:356)
    
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:65)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:205)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:158)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.MediaDownloaderKt.downloadFile(MediaDownloader.kt:49)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived$lambda$0(FirebaseMessagingService.kt:112)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService.$r8$lambda$Jl38Qg36Z_B--LnezsL88ZwrYUo(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:719)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
    
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:569)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:715)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSPResponse.verify(OCSPResponse.java:619)

        ... 50 more
    Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/[2600:9000:20b4:5400:3:24f0:f980:21]:443
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/2600:9000:20b4:5400:3:24f0:f980:21 (port 443) from /fec0::f6d:85d6:8b53:7299 (port 41924) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)

        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:254)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
        ... 18 more
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:356)

        at com.myappapp.myapp.MediaDownloaderKt.downloadFile(MediaDownloader.kt:49)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived$lambda$0(FirebaseMessagingService.kt:112)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService.$r8$lambda$Jl38Qg36Z_B--LnezsL88ZwrYUo(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:719)
    
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:715)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSPResponse.verify(OCSPResponse.java:619)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkOCSP(RevocationChecker.java:709)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:363)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:337)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
        ... 50 more
    Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/[2600:9000:20b4:8800:3:24f0:f980:21]:443
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/2600:9000:20b4:8800:3:24f0:f980:21 (port 443) from /fec0::f6d:85d6:8b53:7299 (port 47678) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:237)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:254)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
        ... 18 more
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:356)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
        
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:158)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.MediaDownloaderKt.downloadFile(MediaDownloader.kt:49)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived$lambda$0(FirebaseMessagingService.kt:112)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService.$r8$lambda$Jl38Qg36Z_B--LnezsL88ZwrYUo(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:719)
    
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:715)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSPResponse.verify(OCSPResponse.java:619)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkOCSP(RevocationChecker.java:709)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:363)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:337)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
        ... 50 more
    Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/[2600:9000:20b4:6600:3:24f0:f980:21]:443
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/2600:9000:20b4:6600:3:24f0:f980:21 (port 443) from /fec0::f6d:85d6:8b53:7299 (port 48548) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:237)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:254)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
        ... 18 more
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:356)
    
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:65)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:205)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:158)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.MediaDownloaderKt.downloadFile(MediaDownloader.kt:49)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived$lambda$0(FirebaseMessagingService.kt:112)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService.$r8$lambda$Jl38Qg36Z_B--LnezsL88ZwrYUo(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.myappapp.myapp.myappFirebaseMessagingService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:719)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
    
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:163)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:260)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1638)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:569)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:715)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSPResponse.verify(OCSPResponse.java:619)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkOCSP(RevocationChecker.java:709)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:363)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:337)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
        ... 50 more
    Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/[2600:9000:20b4:7a00:3:24f0:f980:21]:443
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/2600:9000:20b4:7a00:3:24f0:f980:21 (port 443) from /fec0::f6d:85d6:8b53:7299 (port 42166) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:237)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:254)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
        ... 18 more
    Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/[2600:9000:20b4:ec00:3:24f0:f980:21]:443
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/2600:9000:20b4:ec00:3:24f0:f980:21 (port 443) from /fec0::f6d:85d6:8b53:7299 (port 50870) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:237)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:254)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
        ... 18 more
    Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/[2600:9000:20b4:bc00:3:24f0:f980:21]:443
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/2600:9000:20b4:bc00:3:24f0:f980:21 (port 443) from /fec0::f6d:85d6:8b53:7299 (port 57768) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:237)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:254)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
        ... 18 more
    Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/[2600:9000:20b4:c000:3:24f0:f980:21]:443
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/2600:9000:20b4:c000:3:24f0:f980:21 (port 443) from /fec0::f6d:85d6:8b53:7299 (port 51634) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:237)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:254)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to d3d5vfmrt0s3c6.cloudfront.net/2600:9000:20b4:e00:3:24f0:f980:21 (port 443) from /fec0::f6d:85d6:8b53:7299 (port 56396) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:347)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:237)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket(ConnectPlan.kt:254)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:334)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Check the server using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ It will reveal if something is wrong with the used certificate or the certificate chain.